# How to replace the string in the text if the string is in a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, replace

The dataframe has 2 columns: sentence and list. The requirement is to replace the string in df['sentence'] which is present in df['list'] with string found|present.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = {'list': [['Ford','Mercedes Benz'],['ford','hyundai','toyota'],['tesla'],[]],
        'sentence': ['Ford is less expensive than Mercedes Benz' ,'toyota and hyundai mileage is good compared to ford','tesla is an electric car','toyota too has electric cars']
        }

df = DataFrame(df,columns= ['list','sentence'])
```

The expected output for df['sentence'] is:

```
Ford|present is less expensive than Mercedes Benz|present
toyota|present and hyundai|present mileage is good compared to ford|present
tesla|present is an electric car
toyota too has electric cars
```

Comment: why the last item `toyota too has electric cars` was not modified?

Comment: Because the respective list doesn't have any string to replace. It's an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

With regex replacement:

(cut from *IPython* interactive session)

```
In [36]: import re                                                                                          

In [37]: def sub_from_list(row): 
    ...:     if row['list']: 
    ...:         row['sentence'] =  re.sub(r'({})'.format('|'.join(set(row['list']))), r'\1|present', row['s
    ...: entence']) 
    ...:     return row 
    ...:                                                                                                    

In [38]: df.apply(sub_from_list, axis=1)                                                                    
Out[38]: 
                      list                                           sentence
0          [Ford, hyundai]     Ford|present is expensive than hyundai|present
1  [ford, hyundai, toyota]  toyota|present and hyundai|present mileage is ...
2                  [tesla]                   tesla|present is an electric car
3                       []                       toyota too has electric cars
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using apply function and regex to replace the text inside apply function

```py
import re

df = {'list': [['Ford','Mercedes Benz'],['ford','hyundai','toyota'],['tesla'],[]],
        'sentence': ['Fords is less expensive than Mercedes Benz' ,'toyota and hyundai mileage is good compared to ford','tesla is an electric car','toyota too has electric cars']
        }

df = DataFrame(df,columns= ['list','sentence'])

def replace_values(row):
    if len(row.list)>0:
        pat = r"(\b"+"|".join(row.list) +r")(\b)"
        print(pat)
        row.sentence = re.sub(pat, "\\1|present\\2", row.sentence)
    return row

df.apply(replace_values, axis=1)
```

Comment: The last item (index = 3) is replaced as '|presentt|presento|presenty|presento|presentt|presenta|present |presentt|presento| ..

Comment: @ansev /Dev. Thank you. If we had Fords intead of Ford. The word is replaced as Ford|presents. The exact match would be good. Isn't?

Comment: The new code doesn't replace Fords but it does replace Ford's as Ford|present's. The hyphen S gets added after present. I am looking for an exact string match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function on the data frame as follows:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'list': [['Ford','hyundai'],['ford','hyundai','toyota'],['tesla'],[]],
        'sentence': ['Ford is expensive than hyundai' ,'toyota and hyundai mileage is good compared to ford','tesla is an electric car','toyota too has electric cars']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def rep_text(row):
    if not row.list:
        return row
    words = row.sentence.split()
    new_words = [word+'|present' \
    if word in row.list else word\
    for word in words]

    row['sentence'] = ' '.join(new_words)
    return row

df = df.apply(rep_text, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
                      list                                           sentence
0          [Ford, hyundai]     Ford|present is expensive than hyundai|present
1  [ford, hyundai, toyota]  toyota|present and hyundai|present mileage is ...
2                  [tesla]                   tesla|present is an electric car
3                       []                       toyota too has electric cars
```